# why I cannot create a rigid3d object from this rotation and translation?

Tags: matlab

Here's my code

```
pose2 = rigid3d(R,T');
```

or

```
pose2 = rigid3d([R,T;0 0 0 1]');
```

I do check my rotation matrix R' = inv(R), but I get this error.

> Error using rigid3d (line 143)
> The transformation matrix is not rigid.
> A rigid transformation matrix must only contain a rotation and a translation.
> The final column must consist of zeros, except for a one in the last row.
> Error in SyntheticCalibFace (line 106)
> pose2 = rigid3d(R,T');

```
R =
-4.306559634198784e-01     1.050608066598688e-01    -8.963803144173090e-01
 1.050608066598688e-01     9.922848166308009e-01     6.582605554000008e-02
-8.963803144173090e-01     6.582605554000008e-02     4.383711467890774e-01

T =
     3.114542669304700e+01
    -2.287177166140948e+00
     1.951422849770145e+01
```

Comment: it is probably in how you created `R`, did you use a post-multiply convention ? (or pre multiply),  product of matrices A and B, AB and BA are not the same. when obtaining R...

Comment: From the error message: **The final column must consist of zeros, except for a one in the last row.**

Comment: Your matrix `R` is not a rotation matrix (Just checked its determinant, it is -1).

Comment: Also, although it doesn't matter here, use `.'` for transpose and not `'`

Answer (score 1):

The rotation matrix must satisfy the condition `R * R' = I`.

Try something like this:

```
rigid3d([eul2rotm(rotm2eul(r)) T'; 0 0 0 1]')
```

or

```
rigidtform3d([eul2rotm(rotm2eul(r)) T'; 0 0 0 1])
```

In version R2022b and later, using [`rigidtform3d`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rigid3d.html) is recommended.